# How to fix Windows 7 always delete file permanently

Tags: windows-7, windows, recycle-bin

I am using a laptop from my company, installed with Windows 7. I found that I cannot delete the files to Recycle Bin. The files will always deleted permanently without going to the Recycle Bin.

I am sure that the setting of the Recycle Bin is not "Remove files immediately when deleted".

Then, I checked that, deleting files work fine in other drives, but only `C:` does not work. Besides that, `C:\$RECYCLE.BIN` is missing, but `D:` and `E:` have the `$RECYCLE.BIN`. I think that is why there is no problem other drives to use Recycle Bin.

Please help.

Comment: Try making the $RECYCLE.BIN again. :) idk

Comment: Tried, not work. The folder does not work as real Recycle Bin, no function at all.

Comment: Check to make sure the custom size of the recycle bin is large enough and display confirmation is checked under the recycle bin properties

Comment: I checked. The size of my C: drive Recycle Bin setting is 8422MB

Comment: I would disable and re-enable the Recycle Bin. If that doesn't work, it's possible you have a group policy that is forcing the behaviour you describe (though I'd expect it not to have any Recycle Bin settings at all).

Comment: This solution (restarting in Safe Mode and deleting a file) also worked on a brand new Microsoft Surface running Windows 10 that was missing C:\$RECYCLE.BIN from the very first boot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this [thread](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-7/cant-see-files-in-windows-7-recycle-bin/718.html), one person "fixed" his recycle bin problem by this funny way :

> Ok, what I've done (accidentally, I
>   was working on something else) is
>   booting the computer in safe mode and
>   deleting something. Somehow the
>   recycle bin repaired itself.

Just make sure first in Properties of the recycle bin that enough disk space is allocated for the C drive.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution, enter in safe mode, delete any file, the Recycle Bin appeared.

Comment: I still don't like the fact that this solution did work. It probably means that some product you have installed has blocked the normal functions of Windows.

Comment: Definitely sounds suspicious, unless perhaps this is a case of corporate policy junkware.

Comment: @Rafael Rivera: A very plausible explanation.

Comment: I expect that corporate IT could have helped or informed him if it was `corporate policy junkware`. (Also, WTF only on the C volume and not on the others)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your recycle bin is configured properly, it sounds like you're running into normal behavior. (It's not clear, because you don't indicate what you're deleting.) Be aware, as per [KB320031](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320031), the following deletion actions do not send files to the Recycle Bin, whether or not the Recycle Bin is active:

- Deletions from removable disks (CD-RWs, floppy disks, Zip drives, and other removable disks).
- Deletions from remote shares.
- Deletions from compressed (zipped) folders.
- Deletions at the command line.

Comment: I was deleting files using Windows Explorer, without pressing SHIFT key, just press delete key, even tried with right-click then delete. And also, the files deleted are any files: shortcut files, text files, folders, etc. All of them do not go into Recycle Bin.

Answer (score 1):

Another working solution:

1. Open the drive that has the problem.
2. Open **Folder Options** and show  hidden files and also hidden system files.
3. You will see a folder named **$RECYCLE.BIN** and if you tried to open it you'll find it corrupted.
4. Delete the mentioned folder and the problem is solved!

Comment: But in this case the OP says that `C:\$Recycle.Bin` doesn’t exist.

Comment: @Scott If so, then a [checkdsk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) would help cure corrupted files, also try [sfc /scannow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)

Answer (score 0):

If a file is located on a networked drive and it will be **permanently** deleted because there is no recycle bin for network drives. If you delete the same file from a Library, it will go to the recycling bin on the same drive.

Comment: It was not related to the networked drive.

Answer (score 0):

Right click recycle bin. 
Select "Properties". 
In Settings for selected location you can choose between:
1-The storage size of the recycle bin.
 -or select- 
2-"Don't move files to recycle bin. Remove files immediately when deleted".

The recycle bin is a tool to make sure you don't accidentally delete what you need for whatever...So you can select to display a deletion confirmation dialog if you tend to fudge things up sometimes like so many people do, like I do.

Answer (score -1):

if you find the solution for this type of problem then login in system by administrator account and re-configure the existing currupted profile like permanently delete file from your current login ID.

Comment: You would need to clarify what you mean and provide more details for this answer to be useful, particularly for "re-configure the existing currupted profile".