# Recycle Bin only permanently deletes file

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

Even though the Recycle Bin is not set to permanently delete the files, whenever I delete a file, it is permanently deleted, it does not matter the file size. Prompt asks whether I want to permanently delete the file or not, but there is no option to send the file to the Recycle Bin.

I do not know when this behavior started, but recently my windows was updated:
Edition: Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version: 21H2

[image]

[image]

How can I configure my pc to send the files to the recycle bin, when being deleted?

Comment: Network files will always be permanently deleted. Are your files stored on a network share, or do you have something like redirected folders, etc?

Comment: if you Rclick the Recycle bin > Properties, and select the drive in question, is the option "Don't move files to the recycle bin ..." checked? also, how full is the hard disk?

Comment: @LPChip files are local files. There is a Drive Folder, but I am not using it, nor saving anything on it. Even if I create a blank document in the Desktop and delete it, it will be permanently deleted

Comment: @FrankThomas in both drives the "Don't move files to the recycle bin...' is not checked.  The hard disk has 51.0 GB free, from the 930 GB available.

Comment: Why is Google Drive listed as a recycle bin location?  That does not seem standard.  My suggestion would be to remove that folder.

Comment: One thing I can think of, is that your recycle bin folder is corrupted. You can simply delete the $RECYCLE.BIN folder and reboot to let it be recreated.

Comment: @LPChip  that was it. Deleting it, it was recreated and now it works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Windows 7 always delete file permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/258184/how-to-fix-windows-7-always-delete-file-permanently).  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/258184/how-to-fix-windows-7-always-delete-file-permanently/1387170#1387170) existing answer seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment exchange, it seems like your recycle bin is corrupted.

If you delete the $RECYCLE.BIN folder (or rename it) then reboot, it will be recreated, and should work then.